# Running NM Cable In Attic Along Rafters

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm adding some lighting to the attic and am running wires parallel to rafters. I need to go down the hip rafter and then down another rafter to get to where I need to go. Am I allowed to run the wire underneath the rafter to cross from the hip rafter to the other rafter or does it have to be drilled and through a hole to be up to code?

This is in the attic. Here is a picture of what it looks like. I'd be happy to add any more info if necessary. Thank you.

[image: electric wire under rafters]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run along the side for parallel as you have done,
Going down the “face” of the rafter is ok.  Make sure to stay away from the roof side, you don’t want any future roofing nails punching through the cable.